# How to implement conditional logic in React Form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, react-router, logic

I'm designing a multi-step quiz in Next.js. Basically, it will have a very simple logic that will determine the next question the user has to answer based on what he had answered on the current question.

What I've been doing:

I managed to build a simple form that works without branches and logic.

My challenge is to understand what kind of mechanism available in React I would use to make this survey smarter and conditionally render components based on user answer.

Comment: There really isn't one mechanisim to do this, here are some places to start: you can create a "page" (i.e., a bunch of react components with some conditions put together) for each step in the form. For example, Step1.jsx, Step2.jsx etc etc. Then in each page conditionally show specific components based off of what was answered in the last step and there are many ways you can pass this information between the pages, but the easiest IMO, is using react-router. For example Step 1 url: '/step1'. step2 url: '/step2/past_answer=...' etc.. This is just a place to start, not really a difinitive answer

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did not try approach with routes. My initial idea were to build a survey as SPA, so I created a single page, e.g. survey.js and use an array to track user path. Imagine that I have 20 questions Q1, Q2, ... Q20. Each option in question has its own ID. The next question user will see Is based on option's ID user has selected . So I save user's "survey history" in array and use it to render questions using if...else.

Comment: Ah I see, if you want to stick to that method, a semi-clean way of conditionally displaying components would be to use ternary operators, i.e., `return ({showThisQuestion ? <div>This question</div> : <div>some other question</div>})`, however, I think you may need to rethink your app's design in general because the code is going to get quite messy after a few conditions, good luck!

Comment: Indeed, as complexity of survey growth, the code will become hard to maintain. I will try route approach.

Comment: I will share working example of my code, as I realized that there are few information on the web about survey building with react.